# How to get Ubuntu to utilize my Nvidia GT 520M graphics card?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

- OS: **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**
- Laptop Model: **ASUS K53SJ**
- Graphics card: **Nvidia GeForce GT 520M CUDA 1GB**

Here is the output of my system > details:

[image]

Output of Additional Drivers:

[image]

Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd  
Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller   
[8086:0116]    (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M    
[GeForce GT 520M] [10de:1050] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: It looks like you have installed a legacy driver for older cards. But your chip should work with the newest available. Is this a Optimus dual video system? Be sure to totally purge old driver before installing any newer ones. And often best to use repository or PPA not nVidia directly.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

reboot and run

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Nvidia adapter will be used.

Comment: Did this. Got black screen on reboot. Can`t login via tty. It won't accept my correct password.

Comment: I made a typo in the command. There should be dash in `nvidia-prime`. But the correct password should be accepted either way. Maybe a keyboard layout issue or caps lock?

Comment: Won't work with correct password. Typed it at the login promt to be sure. Anything I can do in recovery mode?

Comment: You can reset your password there http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password/24024?s=1|0.0000#24024

Comment: Did that already. same result. Any way to reset my graphics to Intel?

Comment: You can nothing to do without a password. It is not related to your graphics.

Comment: Ran `prime-switch intel` as root in recovery mode and my system is back running. Only `glxinfo | grep VGA` returns nothing.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` reboot and try to install again.